# How to change the color to only two specific data points in a scatterplot?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUDdq.png)[image]

I am working on a scatterplot in RStudio and am trying to change the color of only two data points from black to red. I have tried commands like `points(bradyscore[-2.0], sum[11.6], col="red")` but it either comes out with an error code saying that the variables are different lengths (which they should not be as it is the coordinates for a data point), or it changes my whole plot by changing the shape of the points, the title and axis. And I also want to color two specific data points not just one. (bradyscore =x and sum=y) there is a categorical variable that is the label for each data point if that is useful in any way. Pictured is the plot that I have now, and I do not want to change anything about the plot except the color of two data points: DC(50,13.9) and Louisiana(-2.0, 11.6). There are 51 total data points.

Comment: please check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Comment: provide the code you have so far

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem with what you did

When isolating one element of a vector, you have to provide its position in the vector:

```
x <- 11:20
x[5]
# [1] 15

x[15]
# [1] NA
# -> there is no 14th element of x, which is of length 10.
```

And in your case the `-2.0` and `11.6` are transformed into integers and used as index:

```
x[-2.0]
# [1] 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# -> removed 2nd element
x[11.6]
# [1] NA
# -> kept the 11th element (which doesn't exist here)
```

Here I guess your `x` and `y` variables are `bradyscore` and `sum`? So you need to find the position of `Louisiana` in these vectors, and use this position as a subscript.

---

Let's start with some data similar to what you have:

```
library(tidyverse)
Guns_data <- tribble(~jurisdiction, ~sum, ~bradyscore,
                     "D.C.",        13.9,        50.0,
                     "Delaware",     6.2,        35.4,
                     "Florida",      5.3,         3.0,
                     "Kentucky",     4.9,        -3.5,
                     "Louisiana",   16.6,        -2.0)
```

### Examples 1: subsetting the data frame

We can directly choose the values from `jurisdiction` that we'll want to color:

```
jurisd_to_color <- c("Louisiana", "Delaware")
```

#### With ggplot2

We can add a column that indicates which color group each jurisdiction belongs to:

```
Guns_data <- mutate(Guns_data,
                    my_colors = if_else(jurisdiction %in% jurisd_to_color,
                                    "to_plot_in_red",
                                    "to_plot_in_black"))

# then plot it
ggplot(Guns_data, aes(x=bradyscore,y=sum,color=my_colors)) +
  geom_point(shape=15) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label=jurisdiction)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","black")) +
  theme_classic()
```

#### With base R

We again add a column with the colors to plot:

```
Guns_data$my_colors <- ifelse(Guns_data$jurisdiction %in% jurisd_to_color,
                          "red",
                          "black")

# Now plot the points
plot(x    = Guns_data$bradyscore,
     y    = Guns_data$sum,
     col  = Guns_data$my_colors,
     pch  = 15,
     xlab = "Brady Score",
     ylab = "Gun Deaths")

# and the labels
text(x      = Guns_data$bradyscore,
     y      = Guns_data$sum,
     labels = Guns_data$jurisdiction,
     col    = Guns_data$my_colors,
     pos=4)
```

### Examples 2: with coordinates

Instead of adding a column to our data frame, we can plot the whole thing in black, and then indicate the coordinates of the points to overplot in red. Here, we will plot Louisiana in red, so `x=-2`, `y=16.6`.

#### With ggplot2

We add a second call to `geom_point` that will overplot on the existing points:

```
ggplot(Guns_data, aes(x=bradyscore,y=sum)) +
  geom_point(shape=15) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label=jurisdiction)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-2.0,y=16.6),
             color="red", shape=15) +
  theme_classic()
```

#### With base R

We can use `points()` to plot on top of the existing figure:

```
plot(x    = Guns_data$bradyscore,
     y    = Guns_data$sum,
     pch  = 15,
     xlab ="Brady Score",
     ylab ="Gun Deaths")

points(x   = -2,
       y   = 16.6,
       col = "red",
       pch = 15)
```

And you can do the same with `text` to overwrite the black text.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions. I am confused at to where you got the numbers in the last two code chunks. You say the last code chunk is 'the best one' to use so I will try that but I am not sure where you are getting the numbers like x <- 1:20
y <- 41:60 and col[10]. so if you could just specify that that would be very helpful.

Comment: `x <-1:20` and `y <- 41:60` are just dummy data, since you didn't provide your data I illustrated with dummy data to made my point clear. `10` should be the index of the point you want to color (e.g. Louisiana). So in that case, I have vectors `x` and `y` for the coordinates, and I create a vector `cols` for the colors. That vector should have "black" everywhere, except for the points that you want to plot in a different color.

Comment: The goal of providing this dummy data is that you can copy it in your own R session and try changing the values until you really understand what each is doing.

Comment: I just added a snapshot of my whole workspace to show you the data and what is not working. If you could help me find a specific working code for this I would appreciate that because nothing is seeming to work.

Comment: I significantly edited my answer to illustrate with data like yours.

Answer (score 1):

in the `points()` function, just give the coordinates of the point which you want to recolor or reshape

```
points(c(50,-2),c(13.9,11.6),col="red")
```

Comment: The `point` function takes a vector of x and y coordinates as parameter. Always read the function description when in doubt. Have a nice day :)